# Java - How to do floor division?

Tags: java, floor-division

I know that in Python you can do floor division like this:

```
5 // 2 #2
```

The `//` is used for something totally different in Java. Is there any way to do floor division in Java?

Comment: Note, though, (if you've been using python3.x) that in Java, dividing two integers will always use floor division.

Comment: Java int division is not quite the same as Python's floor division. `//` rounds towards negative infinity. Java int division rounds towards zero. But `5 / 2` in Java will give you 2, if that is what you're after.

Comment: You are looking for `Math.floorDiv()`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do

```
double val = 5 / 2;
int answer = Math.floor(val);
```

OR

```
int answer = Math.floorDiv(5, 2);
```

If you were to call `System.out.println(answer);` the output would be

> 2

Comment: This isn't even correct. `Math.floor(a / b)` gives the same result as `a / b` when `a` and `b` have type `int`. In Python `5 // -2` gives `-3` where in Java `Math.floor(5 / -2)` gives `-2.0`.

Comment: This is not correct for negative numbers

Answer (score 9):

You can easily use Math.floorDiv() method.
For example:

```
int a = 15, b = 2; 
System.out.println(Math.floorDiv(a, b));
// Expected output: 7
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using integers in the division and you cast the solution to another integer (by storing the result in another integer variable), the division is already a floor division:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
int c = 5/2;
System.out.println(c);
>> 2
```

As khelwood stated, it also works with negative values but the rounding is done towards 0. For example, -1.7 would be rounded to -1.

Answer (score 0):

use floorDiv()

```
int x = 10;
int y = 3;
System.out.println(Math.floorDiv(x,y));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).